# Dovecot mailclient enable archive function

Tags: dovecot

I'd like to archive mails in addition to have the ability to delete an email using my own mailserver. For example when u use iOS Mail, on gmail it displays a archive button instead of a delete button. I'd like to have this functionality on my own server, too.

What is the requirement for this? What and how do I have to configure to enable this?

All searching on this topic resulted in some manuals for gmail, apple software and other things but I didn't find anything which would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That feature is part of the mail app on iOS, not a feature of gmail. If you configure that same gmail account as a generic imap account rather than a gmail account it won't have that button.

Comment: So programs like iOS Mail, Windows mail, etc. just use the information that it is a google server to allow archiving?